# Extracting structure from a memory dump without sourcecode

Tags: c++, debugging, assembly, reverse-engineering, stack-trace

**Issue Summary**
Our company work with a discontinued program.
We have the `.exe` obviously and a `.pdb` (possibly that it doesn't include structures).
The `exe` is a compiled `VC++`.
When the software crashes, it dumps its memory into a `.dmp` which I can open through Visual Studio but since we **do not** have the sourcecode - the information I can extract is very little.
We can see the stack and what the exception is (memory violation) but we need to find out what were the arguments that were passed into the function in order to understand what causes the crash.
The arguments are a pointer to a structure which holds the valuable information.

**Pictures**
The following is what I can view through Visual Studio 2017 (Enterprise) - note: no managed memory debug available.
[image]

Dump Summary (weights 2.4gb, 150mb zipped):
[image]

**Decompiles**
all are via `ida pro` and ordered by the stack:
(0) [`StructItem::deletePendingItem(void)`](http://pastebin.com/Y4vTidwV)
(1) [`StructItem::PendFreeItem_(struct StructItem *a1, const char *a2, int a3)`](http://pastebin.com/vdDp0rjj)
(2) [`onTakeItem(struct StructPlayer *a1, struct TS_CS_TAKE_ITEM *a2)`](http://pastebin.com/shppjrWV)

**For deeper look**
[A rar with the `exe` and `pdb`](https://mega.nz/#!5NUzVCbR!hatv3-rqwcO9l5soxs3d10xNE7AzNK9CRrWeMRUi94k), I'm afraid I cant post here the memory dump but feel free to contact me directly for it.

**What I'm looking for**
There are two structures i'm interested in:
`StructPlayer` and `StructItem`, both can provide me an integer to point towards the database index.
string for `StructItem` is probably stored in the Database and only has a reference to its index.

**My knowledge and skills**
Honestly, I barely know assembly - I have a general picture of what and how.
If the answer could point to a reverse engineering beginner - it would be awesome.

**THE QUESTION**

1. From a memory dump, `exe` and a `pdb` - how can I extract a
   structure data from the called function (showed in the stack)
   directly from the dump.
2. How can I find out the structures data order from a `pdb` and an `exe`
3. Which programs will help me to do that and how.

Comment: Arguments are passed in registers, not on the stack, under x64 Windows. At point of execution shown in your first screenshot those registers would have been overwritten by previous calls to other functions. If the argument is still needed at that point of execution then it would have been moved to another register or saved on the stack. If it's not then its probably lost. In the former case the PDB file should give the debugger enough information to locate the argument, and in that case it should show up under the Locals tab and you can inspect the contents of any structure arguments there.

Comment: The `Locals` window is empty on any of the call stacks, every callstack has different registers - I'll try to surf through those to see if I can get anything.

Comment: Well, if you somehow find the address of one of the structure in memory you should be able to inspect it by putting something like `(struct StructPlayer *) 0x12345678` into the watch window. You can also put some random valid address if you just want to see what members it has. That assumes the PDB file has type information, if not then then only way to find how the structure laid out is by painstakingly analyzing how the code uses the structure.

Comment: I think I managed to isolate a `struct StructPlayer*` through understanding ida decompiled. Upon settings a watch I get 'identifier "StructPlayer" is undefined'.. I also tried to look the structure up in IDA - it seems to be absent/undefined.

Comment: your pdb really not containing type information. only public symbols. all what can be extracted from pdb - [here](https://www.sendspace.com/file/3jebrb) and if you have no src code you can not fix bug in exe, so what is your goal ?

Comment: @RbMm, The software is working mainly with a SQL database - if I can get my hands on either the player id or item id, I'll be able to reproduce and fix the bug.
The bug is caused by a bad row out of >100k rows in the database.

Comment: `StructItem::deletePendingItem()` is static method with no parameters. so really in-depended from `StructItem` and called based on some global conditions - some static var >= 10, time >= lasttime + 100ms

Comment: this may shock you but there is a [reverse engineering site on SE](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) where you can ask questions about reverse engineering